# Some code blocks do not format correctly in IE7

Tags: bug, status-declined, user-interface

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241514/question-about-jquery-performance-and-dom-why-is-one-method-faster-than-the-othe) , for instance, renders in IE7 as a 1-line high textarea with vertical and horizontal scrollbars.   All of the code appears to be on a single line.  Works fine in Firefox 3.5.

Comment: And it doesn't get syntax highlighting, either. Weird.

Comment: The syntax highlighting doesn't work on chrome running on linux.

Answer (score 1):

Weird. Seems to be specific to that code block, as other ones look OK to me in IE8 and IE8 with IE7 mode on.

Probably we won't do anything with this as it appears isolated.

Comment: I've seen it happen on several other questions.  It seems to be triggered when the code contains very long strings AND HTML tags.